# Pl / Sql select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is an databese table;

```
> == id || customer_number || account_type || balance
> == 1   - 123456          -  1              - 100
> == 2   - 123457          -  1              - 200
> == 3   - 123456          -  3              - 200
> == 4   - 123456          -  4              - 220
> == 5   - 123456          -  5              - 250
> == 6   - 123457          -  2              - 200
```

How can I select the customers that have at least one of the types of {1 and 5} ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want customers with accounts of type 1 OR 5:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE account_type IN (1, 5);
```

**[EDIT]** If you want customers with accounts of type 1 AND 5:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c1.customer_number)
FROM customers c1, customers c2
WHERE c1.customer_number = c2.customer_number
    AND c1.account_type = 1
    AND c2.account_type = 5
```

Comment: But what if the customer does not have 5, I only want to see the ones that has both type of 1 and 5 in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

```
select * from table where account_type IN (1,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT customer_number 
FROM customers c 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM customers c1 WHERE c1.account_type = 1 AND c1.customer_number = c.customer_number)
    ) 
AND c.account_type = 5
```